# How to access a React element that has been rendered with renderToString and added with dangerouslySetInnerHTML?

Tags: reactjs, render-to-string, react-dom-server

EDITED: I corrected how I do inject the code, it is not MDX related, it is simply plain html

---

I have `html` code that I insert to my React page with

```js
dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: myContent }}
```

Before, I've added some components to `myContent` with a simple `regex.replace()`, where I've replace some plain text with a React component transformed into plain html with

```js
ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<Input type="text" ref={inputRef}/>)
```

*`<Input>` is a styled component that returns a `<input>` element

However, I cannot access to `inputRef`, nor any `onClick` or `onChange` works

I do think that to enable these event listeners I should `hydrate` the component? Don't really know how it would apply here, and don't really know if `hydrate` is supposed to be applied in this user case (no server involved)

So the objective is that I can interact when this `<input>` is changed, but so far it is absolutely static html that I cannot access to

What could I do?

---

At the end I've added an `<input id="blah"...` and access it with vanilla JavaScript without any apparent trouble

Comment: At the end I'm using vanilla JavaScript here, adding an `id=""` and working with `getElementById` as usual, if anyone has any other suggestion I'm all ears

Comment: First of all. You need hydrate to add listeners and such. But as far as I know hydrate only works for listeners and such, which got attached in the process of a renderToString.

What would be your motivation in rendering the input on the server?

Comment: Here there is no server, but somehow in the documentation it seems that hydrate is applicable when servers are involved? Anyway, how would hydrate work in this case, where I am changing plain html content that I will inject afterwards?